# Best practice: Multiple django applications on a single Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: django, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, gunicorn

I've been runnning a single django application on Amazon EC2 using gunicorn to serve the django portion and nginx for the static files.

I'm going to be starting new project soon, and wondering which of the following options would be better:

1. A larger amazon EC2 instance (Medium) runnning multiple django applications
2. Multiple smallers EC2 instances (Small/Micro) all running their own django applications?

Would anybody have any experience with this? What would the relevant performance metrics I could measure to get a good cost to performance ratio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question really depends on your app I'm afraid. You need to benchmark to be sure you are running on the right instance type. Some key metrics to watch are:

- CPU
- Memory usage
- Requests per second, per instance size
- App startup time

You will also need to tweak nginx/gunicorn settings to make sure you are running with a configuration that is optimised for your instance size.

If costs are a factor for you, one interesting metric is "cost per ten thousand requests", i.e. how much are you paying per 10000 requests for each instance type?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Mike Ryan's answer. I would add that you also have to evaluate whether your app needs a separate database. Sometimes it makes sense to isolate large/complex applications with their own database, which makes changes and maintenance easier. (Also reduces your risk in the case that something goes wrong). Not all of your user base would be affected in the case of an outage. You might want to create a separate instance for these applications. Note: Django supports multiple databases in one project but, again, that increases complexity for changes and maintenance.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).